# How to name the unnamed first column of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
> mydf
                   val1     val2
hsa-let-7a         2.139890 -0.03477569
hsa-let-7b         2.102590  0.04108795
hsa-let-7c         2.061705  0.02375882
hsa-let-7d         1.938950 -0.04364545
hsa-let-7e         1.889000 -0.10575235
hsa-let-7f         2.264296  0.08465690
```

Note that from 3 columns only 2nd and 3rd are names. 
What I want to do is to name the first column (plus rename the 2nd and 3rd).

But why this command failed?

```
colnames(mydf) <- c("COL1","VAL1","VAL2");
```

What's the right way to do it?

It gave me:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("COL1", "VAL1", "VAL2" :
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a column... It looks like they are row names. If you want them as columns then do: `mydf$bla <- rownames(mydf)`

Comment: Is that first "column" just the `rownames`? Try `rownames(mydf)`?

Comment: those are rownames. but it seems to me to be not a great idea to use them as a column in your dataframe, since rownames are metadata, not data?

Comment: In order to understand the error try `ncol(df)`. You will see that the number of columns in your data frame is 2, whereas you supply the vector of length 3. The rest is answered already.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could join the row names to the dataframe, like this:

```
mydf <- cbind(rownames(mydf), mydf)
rownames(mydf) <- NULL
colnames(mydf) <- c("COL1","VAL1","VAL2")
```

Or, in one step:

```
setNames(cbind(rownames(mydf), mydf, row.names = NULL), 
         c("COL1", "VAL1", "VAL2"))
#         COL1     VAL1        VAL2
# 1 hsa-let-7a 2.139890 -0.03477569
# 2 hsa-let-7b 2.102590  0.04108795
# 3 hsa-let-7c 2.061705  0.02375882
# 4 hsa-let-7d 1.938950 -0.04364545
# 5 hsa-let-7e 1.889000 -0.10575235
# 6 hsa-let-7f 2.264296  0.08465690
```

Answer (score 4):

this may also work in your case,

```
mydf <- cbind(rownames(mydf),mydf)
rownames(mydf) <- NULL
colnames(mydf) <- c(names(mydf)) #to not write all the column names

colnames(mydf)[1] <- "name.of.the.first.column" 
names(mydf)
```

Answer (score 4):

If one wants to use a `tidyverse` solution within his/her pipeline, this works

```
rownames_to_column(mydf, var = "var_name")
```

The function is contained in the `tibble` package