# R use if else logic to assign value to new column

Tags: r, substring, sapply

I need to create a new column that is based on one of three possible values found in a column.

These are the rules:

```
If it has c somewhere in it, the new column should be assigned "third"
If it has b, but not c somewhere in it, the new column should be assigned "second"
If it has a but not b or c somewhere in it, the new column should be assigned "first"
```

Here's my sample code

```
x <- c('a,b,c', 'a', 'a,b')

myLetters <- data.frame(x)

setnames(myLetters, "theLetter") 

sapply(myLetters$, theLetter, function(x) 
if ('c' %in% myLetters$theLetter) {
    myLetters$letterStatus <- "third"
} else if ('b' %in% myLetters$theLetter) {
    myLetters$letterStatus <- "second" 
} else if ('a'  %in% myLetters$theLetter) {
    myLetters$letterStatus <- "first"
}
)
```

This is the data I want for each of the rows based upon the sample data for myLetters$letterStatus:

```
Row 1: third
Row 2: first
Row 3: second
```

Currently I'm getting "first" "first" "first" but I don't understand why.

Do you know how I can resolve this and why I got first for each row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using vectorisation (R's gift to us) to obtain the results :

```
x <- c('a,b,c', 'a', 'a,b')
myLetters <- data.frame(x)
# myLetters
# x
# 1 a,b,c
# 2     a
# 3   a,b

myLetters$x1 = ifelse(grepl("c",myLetters$x), "third", ifelse(grepl("b",myLetters$x),"second", "first"))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine and simpler than the sapply code using if else instead of ifelse.

Comment: I have a  followup question: how do i set the column name for myLetters$x1? The name  in View(myLetters$x1) is the set of values it parsed through like c(3, 1, 2), actually it is Null as shown with this command (names(myLetters$letterRating). How can I assign a real column name to it? I see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030728/how-to-name-the-unnamed-first-column-of-a-data-frame but would like to just assign the name of one column, even if there are other columns in the data frame. Thanks

Comment: Actually it worked fine after I refreshed my environment. Thanks

Comment: If you want to replace the column names of a data frame then you can use colnames()